# I have an andengine program that works on one development machine but not another?

Tags: android

For reasons with which I won't bore you, I have to change development computers, and for the life of me I can't get my project to work on the second machine.

I have one library which is a .jar file which both machine have access to. But the program works fine on machine A but on machine B I get the errors below. At first I thought check the manifest, but, exactly the same project works fine on Machine A. So it must be something wrong with my development environment on B. Right? I can't think what it might be. I've got more apis on B than A.

```
04-10 20:21:50.826: W/dalvikvm(1487): Unable to resolve superclass of          Lcom/webs/thefineanimationemporium/BoxingTmcthreeActivity; (117)
04-10 20:21:50.826: W/dalvikvm(1487): Link of class  'Lcom/webs/thefineanimationemporium/BoxingTmcthreeActivity;' failed
04-10 20:21:50.826: D/AndroidRuntime(1487): Shutting down VM
04-10 20:21:50.826: W/dalvikvm(1487): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught      exception (group=0x2aac8578)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.webs.thefineanimationemporium/com.webs.thefineanimationemporium.BoxingTmc threeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.webs.thefineanimationemporium.BoxingTmcthreeActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.webs.thefineanimationemporium-1.apk]
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.webs.thefineanimationemporium.BoxingTmcthreeActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.webs.thefineanimationemporium-1.apk]
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
 04-10 20:21:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1487):    ... 11 more
 04-10 20:21:55.216: I/Process(1487): Sending signal. PID: 1487 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a dodgy install on the second device to me, since one of the classes being called cant be found. Have you tried reinstalling?

edit: Sorry for sounding like someone from a tech support line...

Comment: What do you think might be installed incorrectly? I've copied the project a few times and I've also copied it to another workspace on machine A and it works fine. The .jar library file is the same on both machines. Could it be the android apis?

Comment: Android apis sounds like the most obvious answer now yeah